# How do I plot a Python dictionary key against its corresponding dictionary value?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I am new to Python and I have the following dictionary:

```
results = {50: 18353.8393511688, 100: 18395.2151680032, 150: 18288.730020956387, 200: 18248.345889801505, 250: 18255.26922247291, 300: 18275.241922621914, 350: 18270.29183308043, 400: 18270.197974402367}
```

What I would like to do is to treat each key-value entry as given coordinates and plot (for example using `matplotlib`) the dictionary keys on the y-axis and the dictionary values on the x-axis.

Does anyone know how this information can be extracted?

Thanks!

Marioanzas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the keys and values of a dictionary via their `.keys()` and `.values()` methods, respectively.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.plot(results.keys(), results.values(), 'k-')
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess these methods create corresponding lists which are then used to plot the graph?

Comment: More or less, yes. Technically they are [*view objects*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) that are iterable just like the `list` type.